# How can I authenticate my calls to the StockTwits API?

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, stocktwits

I'm building a StockTwits app in Javascript.

I'm looking at the API documentation on OAuth http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication but confused about how to complete the client-side OAuth flow.

How can I properly authenticate my calls to StockTwits in javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the "Client side OAuth flow" on the [Authentication page](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication).

Once you have a consumer key and consumer secret from registering an app with us, call the authorize end-point with your details:

```
https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&scope=read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,follow_users,follow_stocks
```

Once you or the user authorizes the application from the authentication box, the access token will be passed as a hash in the redirect URI you provided in the authorize call.

Let us know the responses you're getting if it's still not working.

Comment: Can we authorize the call at the server side ?